# Nonstationary and stationaryProblem

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multiarmed-bandit

[image]

[image]

What is the difference between these formulas because I am confused with the difference between them, from what I understand is that the first equation is for stationary situation, while the second one is for non-stationary situation however I do not see the difference between these two, but I was wandering if it meant by changing **1/n** to alpha meant that we can edit how we should update our **Q** Values or what exactly

Comment: Can you give some context on what the terms and the equation represent?

Comment: this is for the multi arm bandits problem in reinforcement learning